# Showing data refresh date in Tableau Desktop

Tags: date, refresh, tableau-api

I want to show the date of the data source refresh but I did not find any Tableau function that can help me.

Do you know?
Thanks.

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/en_US/HowTo/adding-data-refresh-time-stamp-to-view)?

Comment: Thanks, the answer was here: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/en_US/HowTo/adding-data-refresh-time-stamp-to-view

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done. Here are the steps ([found here](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/adding-data-refresh-time-stamp-to-view)):

> Option 1: Add the time stamp to the top of the view

1. Open the workbook that contains the dashboard in Tableau Desktop, and then navigate to the sheet for which you want to display the time of the last data refresh.
2. Select Worksheet > Show Title.
3. Double-click the title.
4. In the Edit Title dialog box, select Insert > Data Update Time, and then click OK.
5. Add any field to the filter shelf and leave all selections blank and click OK.
6. Save the modifications.
7. Add sheet to dashboard.

> Option 2: Add the time stamp to the bottom of the view

1. Open the workbook that contains the dashboard in Tableau Desktop, and then navigate to the sheet for which you want to display the time of the last data refresh.
2. Select Worksheet > Show Caption.
3. Double-click the caption.
4. In the Edit Caption dialog box, select Insert > Data Update Time, and then click OK.
5. Add any field to the filter shelf and leave all selections blank and click OK.
6. Save the modifications.
7. Add sheet to dashboard.
   8 . Right click the sheet and select Caption to show the update time.

These sheets can be sized in the dashboard to take up as much or as little space as necessary. They can also be set up as floating objects so that they do not resize the other sheets in the view.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to:

1. double click on Title (on the Sheet)
2. click the Insert button
3. click Data Update Time